# Need help understanding VS Code programming in Java

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need help understanding what is being printed out on the "terminal" and why it is being printed out. I see that in between all the random lines the code is executed and it actually shows the "Hello, World!" Message, but I would like to better understand why all the extra lines are being printed/shown, if they are useful or not, and how I can get rid of them.

Simple HelloWorld program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Output:

`

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\raymu_000\Documents\Programming\VisualStudioCode\Java_code\Hello>  & 'c:\Users\raymu_000\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.31.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\raymu_000\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\5d3a1b858b2b8ccddbd4be93c8b05273\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Hello_af092f9\bin' 'HelloWorld'
Hello, World!
PS C:\Users\raymu_000\Documents\Programming\VisualStudioCode\Java_code\Hello>
```

`

Screencap of what I see after running the HelloWorld program:
[image: Screencap of what I see after running the HelloWorld program]

Comment: That's literally how running Java in VS Code is supposed to work. I don't know of any way to get rid of them.

Comment: Don't post images of code or output, copy the text of both (with the proper formating) and paste them here directly.

Comment: I made an edit using your advice. Thanks. @Alejandro

Comment: @M-Chen-3
Well, what is it showing anyway?? Is that like the process it takes to compile the code or something?

Comment: @R4Y-Nevarez Yep. It chooses the right directory, compiles, runs, checks for errors, and outputs all in one command. So that's why it's so long.